# Как добавить много вариантов в QComboBox и поставить к каждому значение PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, qcombobox

Для класса `QComboBox` можно добавлять сразу много вариантов через

```
combobox.addItems(['Вариант1','Вариант2','Вариант3'])
```

Но, насколько я понял, таким образом можно вставлять только текст, без значений.

Или же можно добавлять по одному варианту, в этом случае к ним можно выставить значение (или как лучше `setItemData` объяснить)

```
combobox.addItem('Вариант1','Var1Data')
```

Есть ли какой-то способ добавлять много вариантов сразу (передавая аргументом лист/словарь, например), при этом выставляя каждому значение, да так, чтобы обойтись без циклов и без переопределения класса `QComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен что правильно понял ваш вопрос, но предложу попробовать.

> void QComboBox::**setItemData**(int index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::UserRole)
>
> Устанавливает роль данных для элемента по заданному индексу
> в поле со списком на указанное значение.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QComboBox, \
    QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.categories = {
            'Животные':['кошка', 'собака', 'попугай', 'слон'],
            'Цветы': ['ромашки', 'тюльпаны', 'нарциссы', 'розы'],
            'Цвета': ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'purple']
        }
                           
        self.category_combobox  = QComboBox(self)
        
        self.item_combobox = QComboBox(self)

        self.category_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.set_category)
        self.category_combobox.addItems(sorted(self.categories.keys()))
        
        self.item_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.set_item)   

        form_layout = QFormLayout(self)
        form_layout.addRow('Category', self.category_combobox)
        form_layout.addRow('Items', self.item_combobox)

    def set_category(self, text):
        print(f"set_category -> {text}")
        self.item_combobox.clear()
        self.item_combobox.addItems(self.categories.get(text, []))

        if text == 'Цвета':
            for i, color in enumerate( self.categories['Цвета'] ):
                self.item_combobox.setItemData(i, QColor(color), Qt.BackgroundRole)
        
    def set_item(self, text):
        if text:
            print(f"set_item -> {text}")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @declider что не так?